# HmCharacteristic.readValue always crashes with bundleID is invalid and XPC not entitled

Tags: ios, swift, entitlements, homekit, xpc

I want to print out every hmCharacteristic's value in my Smart Home and therefore created this screen (code see below).

Unfortunately, I am always getting these two errors whenever I try to call the `HmCharacteristic.readValue()` function (error messages see below).

I am using a physical test iPhone with a real HomeKit Smart Home (no HomeKitAccessorySimulator).

I am also using a paid apple developer Account and did enable the HomeKit entitlement as well as allowed the app to use HomeKit data on my test iPhone.

**My question is: Why do I get the `bundleId is invalid` and `XPC not entitled` errors and how do I fix them?**

```
import SwiftUI
import HomeKit

struct screen: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }

    init() {
        let hmHomeManager = HMHomeManager();
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            for hmHome in hmHomeManager.homes {
                for hmRoom in hmHome.rooms {
                    for hmAccessory in hmRoom.accessories {
                        for hmService in hmAccessory.services {
                            for hmCharacteristic in hmService.characteristics {
                                Task {
                                    hmCharacteristic.readValue { error in
                                        print("\(hmHome.name)/\(hmRoom.name)/\(hmAccessory.name)/\(hmService.name)/\(hmCharacteristic.localizedDescription) = \(hmCharacteristic.value ?? "[[nil]]")")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        screen()
    }
}
```

```
validateSessionInfo: bundleID is invalid. Please specify the bundleID for kRTCReportingSessionInfoClientBundleID
initWithSessionInfo: XPC not entitled, 1
```